# Save button state android

Tags: android, button, click, state

I am making a news application which has a bookmark functionality. When user clicks on bookmark button the image is changed and bookmark is saved and again clicking on that removes the bookmark. But when i go to some other activity and then come back to main news page the bookmark button image is again changed to default one.

Button is not able to retain state.

I tried it with on touch also , but no success

```
newsHolder.bookmark.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(!isBookmarked) {
                    isBookmarked = true;
                    newsHolder.bookmark.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_bookmark);
                    newsObject.setTitle(currentNews.getmTitle());
                    newsObject.setDescription(currentNews.getmDescription());
                    newsObject.setDate(currentNews.getmPublishedAt());
                    newsObject.setPoweredBy(poweredby);
                    newsObject.setImageUrl(currentNews.getmUrlToImage());
                    newsObject.setSource(currentNews.getmSource());
                    newsObject.setUrl(currentNews.getmUrl());

                    newsDbHelper.addNews(newsObject);
                    newsHolder.bookmark.setPressed(true);
                    Toast.makeText(activity, "Bookmark Added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else
                {

                    newsHolder.bookmark.setPressed(false);
                    newsDbHelper.deleteBookmark(currentNews.getmUrl());
                    isBookmarked = false ;
                    newsHolder.bookmark.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_add_bookmark);



                    Toast.makeText(activity, "Bookmark Removed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should save your bookmarked articles in some persistent storage Prefs/BD/Cloud and check is it bookmarked or not when launching screen and change state of button according to it.

Comment: so check DB for specific ID and if it is in DB make button looks like it bookmarked

Comment: See when I click on button, image is successfully changed to bookmarked image and it is saved in database. I have a view-pager on home activity . When i go to other page and come back to previous page the image is changed back to add bookmark.

Comment: Update your question and show the code where you check state

Comment: @ParasWatts you should check your DB for specific bookmark in onResume callback of your fragment

Answer (score 0):

You have two options to do that, one is to save the book mark state of each item on server, by default it should be false and on clicking on it, update the value.

But I guess you are getting those news through a Third Party server, maybe RSS feeds of some news channel, you are not getting those news from your own server, so you cannot make changes on server.

Best solution that I can suggest to you is that you should create a Local Database, in which you will save the state of bookmark against the id of that specific item (There must be a unique id for each news item coming from news server). After that you will set the news from server but you will check the state of book mark for each item from your Local Database. When user will interact with the book mark button you will make the changes against the specific id on that position accordingly in your Database.